# How to style using d3's .style() method instead of using CSS in style tags for .axis path {}?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have this d3 code here of an area chart. My question is primarily about styling the axis and the tick marks.

Currently the x axis and y axis are styled like this:

```
  .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: red;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

  .axis path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: blue;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
```

I don't want to use this approach. Let's say I want to change the stroke color of axis (to green), using d3's style() method in my javascript.
I tried doing it like this:

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .style("stroke", "green")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
```

What I ended up changing is the axis text labels to green color. This is not what I intended to do.

What am I missing ?

How do I style .axis line and .axis path using style() method of my d3.

[Please find me code here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akashdmukherjee/6umuko34/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use javascript

After drawing the axis using selectAll method you can change the colors.

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .style("stroke", "green")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

 svg.selectAll(".x.axis *").style({"stroke":"red"});
```

I just given an example changed all color to red. you can change only ticks or text color that you want to change.

For line and path use

```
svg.selectAll(".x.axis line, .x.axis path").style({"stroke":"red"});
```

But I will prefer to use CSS only for changing color.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to apply the styles to the necessary `line` and `path` elements as in CSS and not to the `g` element. G elements are used to group children. The style attributes you give to it are given down to its children.

```
d3.selectAll(".axis").selectAll("line").style({"stroke":"red", "fill":"none", "shape-rendering": "crispEdges"});    
d3.selectAll(".axis").selectAll("path").style({"stroke":"green", "fill":"none", "shape-rendering": "crispEdges"});
```

```js
var data = {
  "Series 1": {
    "20141020": 3.5003987252672744,
    "20141019": 2.505802351020492,
    "20141018": 1.511804171940014,
    "20141015": 1.466520821512944,
    "20141014": 2.458051096911987,
    "20141017": 0.518412786499141,
    "20141016": 0.4743643618143949,
    "20141013": 3.4489507475146013
  },
  "Series 2": {
    "20141008": 3.386547593121662,
    "20141009": 2.1369256424188166,
    "20141011": 0.3631764039020311,
    "20141010": 0.8870161087572228,
    "20141013": 2.8643781772248076,
    "20141012": 1.6136442355091276
  },
  "Series 3": {
    "20141024": 1.041445076319178,
    "20141025": 1.1241181263211502,
    "20141026": 1.38667149365412,
    "20141027": 1.818787980672198,
    "20141020": 2.5807963840540538,
    "20141021": 1.9209716474825598,
    "20141022": 1.4397443637179492,
    "20141023": 1.1457284782715362,
    "20141028": 2.4079290114153764,
    "20141029": 3.1402443065157684,
    "20141019": 3.4040698638675053
  },
  "Series 4": {
    "20141015": 0.6342340828370823,
    "20141014": 0.5870678384520431,
    "20141017": 3.0054047120678433,
    "20141016": 1.8435837647016058,
    "20141011": 3.997287602433431,
    "20141013": 1.786070641215474,
    "20141012": 2.9316731724834995
  },
  "Series 5": {
    "20141024": 2.1140684266577807,
    "20141025": 2.0313953766558086,
    "20141026": 1.7688420093228387,
    "20141027": 1.3367255223047607,
    "20141020": 0.574717118922905,
    "20141021": 1.234541855494399,
    "20141022": 1.7157691392590095,
    "20141023": 2.0097850247054225,
    "20141030": 0.8458214720297121,
    "20141028": 0.7475844915615824,
    "20141029": 0.015269196461190404,
    "20141019": 0.24855636089054656,
    "20141018": 1.2136523216203159,
    "20141017": 2.2931197800781717,
    "20141016": 3.4549407274444093
  }
}

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, height]);

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left");

var area = d3.svg.area()
  .interpolate("basis")
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(parseDate(d.key));
  })
  .y0(height)
  .y1(function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var entries = d3.entries(data);

color.domain(entries.map(function(d) {
  return d;
}));

var minX = d3.min(entries, function(kv) {
  var entry = d3.entries(kv.value);
  return d3.min(entry, function(d) {
    return parseDate(d.key);
  })
});
var maxX = d3.max(entries, function(kv) {
  var entry = d3.entries(kv.value);
  return d3.max(entry, function(d) {
    return parseDate(d.key);
  })
});
var minY = d3.min(entries, function(kv) {
  var entry = d3.entries(kv.value);
  return d3.min(entry, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
});
var maxY = d3.max(entries, function(kv) {
  var entry = d3.entries(kv.value);
  return d3.max(entry, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
});

x.domain([minX, maxX]);
y.domain([minY, maxY]);

var element = svg.selectAll(".element")
  .data(entries)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "element");

element.append("path")
  .attr("class", "area")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    var entry = d3.entries(d.value);
    return area(entry);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.key);
  });

element.append("text")
  .datum(function(d) {
    var entry = d3.entries(d.value);
    return {
      name: d.key,
      date: parseDate(entry[entry.length - 1].key),
      value: entry[entry.length - 1].value
    };
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.date) + "," + y(d.value) + ")";
  })
  .attr("x", -6)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });

svg.append("g")

.attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

.call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis);

d3.selectAll(".axis").selectAll("line").style({
  "stroke": "red",
  "fill": "none",
  "shape-rendering": "crispEdges"
});
d3.selectAll(".axis").selectAll("path").style({
  "stroke": "green",
  "fill": "none",
  "shape-rendering": "crispEdges"
});
```

```css
body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    .element text {
      text-anchor: end;
    }
    .area {
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```